# Can we omit age from "at the age of 10" and say "at 10"? Is that informal?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I am wondering what's the difference between

> I started to walk at three

and the following variants:

> 1. I started to walk at the age three.
> 2. I started to walk at age of three.
> 3. I started to walk at age three.

Comment: You missed the one I would say: "I started to walk at age three".

Comment: None of your variants are acceptable. Either *I started smoking **at** 15* or *I started smoking **at age** 15*, unless you go for the full-blooded verbosity of *I started smoking **at the age of** 15*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Variant #3 is acceptable

Comment: @chevybow He said that before I edit the question. It had a minor issue originally.

Comment: Please furnish the OP with your opinion when down-voting a question, that would make the world a better place in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked about differences between your initial sentence and the other three. One is that your initial sentence could be taken to mean that the speaker started to walk at three o’clock, rather than at age three. For example:

> **I started to walk at three,** and by five or five fifteen I had reached the town.

That ambiguity does not exist in the other three sentences.

Aside: although all of those other three are sufficiently clear for me to be able to make the above comment (i.e. they’re all referring to the speaker’s age when he began to walk as a child), only the third is idiomatic.